# Standard SQL not raising exceptions for non-existing tables when using table wildcard function

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-bigquery

When querying tables with date partition suffix, we have the wildcard function for both Legacy SQL and Standard SQL. However, I found that they are not working exactly in the same way, and Standard SQL will not raise the exception even though the table for a particular date doesn't exist.

For examples, I have a set of tables called `myTable_YYYYMMDD`, but missing table 'myTable_20170601', then,

**In Legacy SQL**,

```
 Select *
 From table_date_range([project_id:datasetName.myTable_],
 timestamp('20170601'), timestamp('20170601'))
```

It will give me [ *Errors:
query: FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table (error code: invalidQuery)* ]

**In Standard Query,**

```
Select *
From `project_id.datasetName.myTable_*`
where _table_suffix between '20170601' and '20170601'
```

And this will give me an empty result instead of an exception even though the table is not available.

In this case, If I am running an automated job to query again the tables and empty table is also one of the expected results, then I wouldn't know the source table doesn't exist, which affect the real result.

Is that possible to have the exception raised in Standard SQL too?

Thank you in advance.

---

**Add a feature request on BigQuery Issue Tracker**

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62264827

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is that if you know a particular table should exist, you can query just that table or take a union with it (if you are querying multiple dates). For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM `project_id.datasetName.myTable_20170601`;
```

Or, for multiple dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM `project_id.datasetName.myTable_20170601` UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM `project_id.datasetName.myTable_*`
 WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170516' AND '201706531');
```

In either case, the query will fail if the table for June 1 does not exist. Alternatively, you can trigger a failure if the number of `_TABLE_SUFFIX` is zero through division:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT *, _TABLE_SUFFIX AS suffix
  FROM `project_id.datasetName.myTable_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170601' AND '20170601'
)
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(suffix),
  1 / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT suffix) FROM T)
FROM T;
```

Edit: If anyone else would like to follow Haipeng's feature request, you can find it [in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62264827).

Comment: Hi, Elliott, this is definitely a bypass solution. However, for automated jobs, I query single day's table based on the date string and then pass it to the query in Datalab. Then solution #1 won't work because I can't pass the table name itself to SQL magic cell. For solution #3, for each query against daily tables, I have to put extra steps to verify the existence of the table, which works but always not pretty.

Comment: Is that means Standard SQL won't check whether the table exists or not just like Legacy SQL? Or could it be a feature request? Thank you so much, Elliott.

Comment: WHERE clauses only exclude rows--it doesn't make sense to have a query fail for excluding all of them. You could consider [submitting a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) for a function that can trigger an error, though.

Comment: thank you, the new query should work as expected. Submitting a feature request might be a better idea.

Comment: I will accept your answer, and add a feature request on Google Issue Tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62264827